# how does hystrix ensure fast recovery?

Tags: hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I understood it helps to fail-fast. But how does it ensure fast recovery for vendors? 
It can probably recover faster in case it is taking a lot of time to handle current request and other requests are stopped using fail fast. But what are the other scenarios where/how it can ensure fast recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hystrix does not really ensure fast recovery. It can only help not to overload the remote service you are calling by reducing the number of requests if the latency is high or there are too many failures in a row. In that case the other service has more time to recover (if possible) and get back to a normal state.

However, Hystrix is more about making your service resilient to the failures of the services it depends on. It does not really care much about how to fix those failures but tries to keep your service operational in some limited mode and not to cascade those failures to the consumers of your service.